# How to force a webbrowser to download content in advance?

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache

I got a "steps" website which means users enter the site, do some taksks, then click "next" and go to another step. In the end of these steps, there're some videos played. Is that possible to force users to download these particular videos while they're in the very first steps so they can be played smoothly when neccessary? Maybe there're some caching mechanism I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Load them in normally using HTML, then set display none on them. When you need them, make them visible.

Comment: Since every step is a separate .html file, I can't solve it like that.

Comment: You could load those HTML files in using JavaScript, would that work?